# Tcp Listener dies after about 50 hours

Tags: c#-4.0

I have create a tcp listener in C#. I have set timeout to 0 with unlimited time. If there is  no activity about 50 hours like on weekends between listener and client, but not disconnect. It dies

Please advice how can i fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of application hosts this listener?  Is something in the OS perhaps terminating the process?

Comment: No, process is still running, I am not sure it is the .NET issue or something else

Comment: Please clarify if the program stops *listening* for connections, or if an existing but idle *connection* is terminated.  Also, can you test with a direct wired connection between the two systems, to rule out anything imposed by a service provider or network unreliability?  Determining the specific timeout could be helpful, ie is it consistent or random?  You may need to implement keep alive traffic at an interval.

Comment: process is still runnung because some inner thread was not terminated

Answer (score 0):

Routers will typically kill idle TCP connections after a preset amount of time. If your connection is going over the internet you have no control over this. To prevent the problem programmatically detect your idle connections and send a very small amount of information, i.e. `byte[] { 0 };` every 5 minutes or so.

This adds no overhead as if the connection is active you do not send the '[keep alive packet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive)'.

Another option is to set the 'KeepAlive' option on the underlying sockets using [`Socket.SetSocketOption'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e160993d.aspx). This should perform the same function but I've always found a custom solution more reliable.

Comment: How exactly do you send such a packet from within a listener?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - I would suggest either on the underlying TCPListener socket or using a custom solution that sends packets manually once a connection has been established (via TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient).

Comment: The way I understand the OP there are no clients connected when this occurs.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - I am happily wrong but I read "about 50 hours like on weekends between listener and client" to mean that there is an established connection.